Integración del sistema de pago "insite" redsys con angular
estoy tratando de implementar en mi el sistema insite de redsys en mi web con angular. La documentación es un poco escueta al respecto y estoy intentando adaptarla como puedo.
En mi componente html tengo esto:
<div id="card-form" style="height:400px"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="token">
<input type="hidden" id="errorCode">

En mi componente typescript esto:
declare var getInSiteForm: any;
declare var storeIdOper: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-redsys-payment',
    templateUrl: './redsys-payment.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./redsys-payment.component.scss'],
})
export class RedsysPaymentComponent implements OnInit {
    fuc = '999008881'
    terminal = '1'

    ngOnInit(): void {
    // Listener para la recepción del token
    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
      if (event.origin !== 'http://localhost:8100'){
        storeIdOper(event, "token", "errorCode", this.merchantValidationEjemplo());
      }
    });
    getInSiteForm('card-form', '', '', '', '', 'Pagar', this.fuc, this.terminal, 'ped4227', 'ES', true, false, 'twoRows');

}
Esto me renderiza perfectamente el formulario para introducir los datos de la tarjeta. Pero cuando hago click en el botón de pagar no ocurre absolutamente nada. Si no entiendo mal al hacer click en el botón deberia dispararse un evento 'message' con origin de redsys pero no ocurre nada.
